# Qual a forma correta de declarar uma função main()?

Tags: c, funções, sintaxe

Em algumas pesquisas que realizei, notei que há alguns meios diferentes de faze-la, como os exemplos abaixo:

```
int main()
int main(void)
void main()

// entre outros...
```

Sei que as declarações são inteiramente ligadas aos comandos `return`, sendo necessário por exemplo retornar algum numero inteiro no tipo de função `int` e que a `void` não me retorna nada.

Gostaria de uma explicação mais detalhada quanto a sintaxe e a obrigatoriedade desses exemplos.

Comment: eu já vi `void main(void)` também =P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ambas funcionam na maioria dos compiladores. Pode depender da opção ligada e ao padrão que deseja atender.

A recomendação costuma ser usar pelo menos o padrão C99 onde estas duas formas são aceitas:

```
int main(void)
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/MainSignature.c).

Mas alguns preferem o padrão C89 que é mais compatível com compiladores não modernos (raros, mas encontrados em plataformas embarcadas). Aí o `void` como parâmetro pode ser evitado (sem trocadilho :P). Se for seguir o padrão do C++ ele também é evitado.

O uso do [`void` indica que a função não tem parâmetro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138582/101). Se não tiver nada, ela tem um número de parâmetro indefinidos e a implementação pode ter os parâmetros que quiser. Isto pode gerar confusão em alguns casos.

O retorno sempre deve ser `int`, ainda que alguns compiladores aceitem outro tipo, especialmente o `void`. No C89 é necessário dar o `return` com um número inteiro. No C99 isto pode ser implícito, ele retorna 0 para você.

Lembrando que alguns compiladores podem não estar totalmente dentro do padrão e exigir uma forma diferente.

A melhor é a segunda. A primeira é aceitável quase sempre e a última não deve ser usada.

Especificação:

> 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup

> The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:

> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):

> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> or equivalent; or in some other implementation-defined manner.