# Qual a finalidade do parâmetro void em funções na linguagem C?

Tags: c, funções, parâmetros, void

O parâmetro `void` é apenas semântico ou ele faz alguma coisa que eu não saiba?

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual é a finalidade do void em C?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97138/qual-%c3%a9-a-finalidade-do-void-em-c)

Comment: @diegofm na verdade isto não tem na pergunta *linkada*.

Comment: eu tinha acabado de ler esta pergunta @diegofm e nao ea mesma coisa

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Neste caso são [definições de funções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101). Ele define que a função só poderá ser chamada com nenhum [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) sendo passado. Sem o `void` pode chamar com passagem de argumentos.

Veja não [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/vGtGs9). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zofuttmx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/Void.c).

Se fossem declarações, aí seria diferente. Veja abaixo:

```
int funcao(void);
int funcao() {
    return 0;
}

int funcao2();
int funcao2(int x, int y) { //válido
    return 0;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/VoidReturn.c).

Na declaração do protótipo o `void` indica que nenhum parâmetro poderá ser usado na definição da implementação da função.

Ao contrário do que muitos imaginam e como funciona em outras linguagens o uso da [assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) da função `funcao()` significa apenas que nenhum parâmetro está definido explicitamente, dando a liberdade para fazer como quiser.

O recomendável, em C, é sempre usar o `void` na declaração do protótipo, se esta estiver presente. Em C++ não é necessário, a linguagem assume que não haverá parâmetros.

[Pergunta que já fala da especificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95133/101).

Comment: Segundo o padrão C99, a definição de funções não é recomendada pois está obsoleta: ISO/IEC 9899 - 6.11.7  - Function definitions: The  use  of  function  definitions  with  separate  parameter identifier and declaration lists
(not prototype-format parameter type and identifier declarators) is an obsolescent feature.

Comment: @Lacobus deixa o link do artigo sobre o  padrão C99

Answer (score 3):

Em C, quando a assinatura de uma função possui apenas o parametro `void` significa que tal função não recebe nenhum parametro quando chamada.

Existe uma grande diferença entre `int foobar();` e `int foobar( void );`. No primeiro caso, a função foi apenas declarada e não possui um protótipo, já no segundo caso, a função foi declarada juntamente com um protótipo.

Segundo o padrão C99, a definição de funções não é recomendada pois está obsoleta, vejamos:

**6.11.6 Function declarators**

> The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter type declarators) is an obsolescent
>   feature.

**6.11.7 Future language directions, Function declarators**

> The  use  of  function  definitions  with  separate  parameter
>   identifier and declaration lists (not prototype-format parameter type
>   and identifier declarators) is an obsolescent feature.

Não é necessário usar `void` ao declarar/implementar uma função que não recebe nenhum parametro, porém, é uma boa prática que tem como objetivo otimizar a legibilidade e o entendimento do código, facilitando a diferenciação de quando a função está sendo chamada e de quando ela está sendo declarada.

Somente Declaração:

```
int foobar(); /* Evite Declarar Funções Sem Protótipo! */
```

Declaração e protótipo:

```
int foobar( void ); /* Boa Prática! */
```

Definição/Implementação:

```
int foobar( void ){
    return 0;
}
```

Chamada:

```
n = foobar();
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: suspeitei desde o principio