# O que significa e qual é a finalidade do 'return 0'?

Tags: c, c++, return

Recentemente começei alguns estudos sobre C/C++ e na grande maioria dos exemplos iniciais que vi, me deparei com `return 0` no final do código.

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        cout << "Hello World!";
        return 0;
    }
```

Esse `return 0` realmente retorna zero? Qual é sua finalidade?

**Fontes**

- [cplusplus - Structure of a program](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/program_structure/)
- [CodingUnit - First C++ program, hello world](https://www.codingunit.com/cplusplus-tutorial-first-cplusplus-program-hello-world)
- [Wikiversity - Curso de C++/Programa HelloWorld](https://pt.wikiversity.org/wiki/Curso_de_C%2B%2B/Programa_HelloWorld)
- [University of Michigan - Hello world! Example Program (The C++ Programming Language)](http://groups.engin.umd.umich.edu/CIS/course.des/cis400/cpp/hworld.html)

Comment: Legal, agradeço sua atenção!

Comment: dei uma leve editadinha na reposta aceita, acho que dá pra entender melhor.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95133/101

Comment: @ViníciusBrasil na verdade nem tava tao ruim, só o jeito que ele separou as informações tava meio confuso. Só não quis mexer mais, pq apareceu mais uma resposta lá. De qq forma, se tiver algo que não entendeu comente aqui.